# Verify pdf contents not altered with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm working on a service to do the following:

1. User downloads a PDF
2. User signs PDF in his own computer
3. User re-uploads PDF with the signature

I need a way to verify that the content of the downloaded PDF is the same as the newly uploaded PDF with the signature.
This is required so that an evil user wont upload a subtly different PDF.

I'm using PDFBox on the server. Is there a safe way to compare only the content of PDF files, ignoring the signatures?

Comment: PDF format supports what are called Incremental saves, which means all changes are appended to the end of the original PDF. So you could do binary compare on the original bytes, and then "analyze" the incremental save to ensure only the signature was added.

Comment: The user, though, signs on his own computer, presumably using the signing software of his choice. Thus, he probably will not use incremental updates. *Unless you force him to*, e.g. by applying an author signature first.

Comment: Nonetheless, already *analyzing the incremental update* for unwanted changes is apparently not trivial, just remember the shadow attacks published on pdf-insecurity.org this year.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! What do you think about this workflow: when the user downloads the pdf it includes a server digital signature that contains an internal uuid that identifies the file in the server. When I receive the uploaded file from the user I check the uuid in the server digital signature to match it against the right file. This way, the user can't upload a different file unless he gets access to the server private key.

Comment: Instead of an arbitrary UUID i would propose you use the document hash signed by the signature. Nonetheless you still have to check the additions by the user in the incremental update. If the user only uses standard software (e.g. Adobe Acrobat), that software will not allow most kinds of changes. But if the user uses own programs, there can be arbitrary changes in the incremental update. And as mentioned above, analyzing the incremental updates for disallowed changes is not trivial.